# Not able to start service when app is in background

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want to start service to play mp3 url when push notification is received but when app in background or idle service doesn't start due to android restriction policy here is my code so doing with notification.
I am also using data payload its working fine app is in foreground but the problem is coming when app goes to background.

**My FirebaseMessaging Class**  where staring the service

```
 val resultIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MusicService::class.java)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("title", title)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("body", body)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("action_type", action_type)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("deep_link_type", deep_link_type)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("deep_link_id", deep_link_id)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("masjid_Id", masjid_Id)
                        resultIntent.putExtra("url", url)
                        Log.i("***TAG", "From Background")
                        resultIntent.setAction("com.example.mymasjid");
//                        resultIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                        startService(resultIntent) 


**My Music Service Class** 


class MusicService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    var objService: MusicService? = null
    var title: String = ""
    var body: String = ""
//    private val mBinder: IBinder = LocalBinder()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
//        if (title.isNotEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty())
            adhanNotification(title, body)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
//        val url = intent!!.getStringExtra("url")
         title = intent!!.getStringExtra("title").toString()
         body = intent!!.getStringExtra("body").toString()
//        if (title!!.isNotEmpty() && body!!.isNotEmpty())
            Log.i("***TAG","From Background Service")
            adhanNotification(title, body)
        val url = "https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/64/ar.alafasy/9.mp3"
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer!!.stop()
            mediaPlayer!!.release()
            mediaPlayer = null
        }
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mediaPlayer!!.setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                    .build()
            );
        } else {
            mediaPlayer!!.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource(url)
            mediaPlayer!!.prepare()
            mediaPlayer!!.start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        mediaPlayer!!.setLooping(false)
        mediaPlayer!!.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onPrepared(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
        mediaPlayer!!.start()
        Log.i("***play", "play")
    }

    override fun onCompletion(p0: MediaPlayer?) {
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        Log.i("***play", "complete")
        stopSelf()
        /* mediaPlayer!!.release()

         mediaPlayer=null*/
    }

    override fun onError(p0: MediaPlayer?, p1: Int, p2: Int): Boolean {
        Log.i("***play", "error")
        return false
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        isServiceRunning = false
        objService = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun adhanNotification(title: String, body: String) {
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "notify_001")
        val collapsedView = RemoteViews(
            packageName,
            R.layout.notification
        )
        val expandView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_expand)

        val onCancelIntent = Intent(this, CancelNotification::class.java)
        val onDismissPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getService(this.applicationContext, 0, onCancelIntent, 0)

        val time = Utility.getTime("LLL dd, KK:mm aaa")
        collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNotifyTime, time)
        collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title)
        collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.body, body)
        expandView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNotifyTime, time)
        expandView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title)
        expandView.setTextViewText(R.id.body, body)
//        val switchIntent = Intent(this, BackgroundService.switchButtonListener::class.java)

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(onDismissPendingIntent)
        //mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
        mBuilder.setOngoing(false)
        /*    if (sound=="default")
                mBuilder.setSound(uri)
            else if (sound=="silent")
                mBuilder.setSilent(true)*/
        mBuilder.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH
//        mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
        mBuilder.build().flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR or Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH
        //mBuilder.setCustomContentView(contentView)
        mBuilder.setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
        mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(expandView)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channelId = "channel_id"
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(channelId, "channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId)
        }
        val random = (0 until 100).random()
        val notification = mBuilder.build()
        notificationManager.notify(random, notification)
    }

    companion object {
        var isServiceRunning = false
        var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think its possible any more, AFAIK there were new restriction which does not allow service to start from background.

Comment: yeah, I know about the restriction but I need to play music when push notification received. I'm getting music url in push notification need to play it if push receives.

Comment: Then you must start a activity when you receive a push notification.

Comment: Thank you, It's resolved with notification tray.

Comment: You can call broadcast receiver and play there